# Racket Scheme - Removing Duplicate Consecutive Characters from Stream

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to implement a function that recursively removes all extra spaces from a given stream. Any consecutive spaces should be removed, allowing for one maximum space inbetween words. I cannot figure out how to implement this correctly.

I have tried converting the stream to a list and manipulating it that way, but I simply cannot figure out how to construct a new stream and return it, based on what my tests for each element provide. I have attempted to use stream-map, but it does not seem to work for me in this situation (removing elements, constructing new stream)

Here is my current broken implementation of remove-extra-spaces:

```
    (define remove-extra-spaces
  (lambda (str)
    (cond (not (not-more-than-one-space str 0) (stream-append (stream-first str) (remove-extra-spaces (stream-rest str))))
          (else (remove-extra-spaces (stream-rest str)))
          )))


    (define not-more-than-one-space
  (lambda (str count)
      (cond ((stream-empty? str) #T)
            ((equal? (stream-first str) #\space) (not-more-than-one-space (stream-rest str) (+ count 1)))
            ((> count 1) #F)
            (else #T)
            )
    ))
```

I wrote a test to help me find when there are multiple consecutive spaces. However, I cannot figure out how to use this test to create a new stream based on what passes it. Stream-filter did not work for me when i attempted to use it in conjunction with stream-map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to use `stream-cons`? That is probably the easiest way to implement this. Here's my implementation (uses [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) stream library instead of `racket/stream` because I'm more familiar with that):

```
(require srfi/41)
(define-stream (collapse-spaces strm)
  (stream-let loop ((was-space #f)
                    (strm strm))
    (cond ((stream-null? strm) strm)
          ((char=? (stream-car strm) #\space)
           (if was-space
               (loop #t (stream-cdr strm))
               (stream-cons #\space (loop #t (stream-cdr strm)))))
          (else (stream-cons (stream-car strm)
                             (loop #f (stream-cdr strm)))))))
```

Sample run:

```
> (stream->list (collapse-spaces (stream #\f #\o #\o #\space #\space #\b #\a #\r)))
(#\f #\o #\o #\space #\b #\a #\r)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into using stream-cons. I applied it into my remove-extra-spaces function, however I get thrown an error when I try to convert it to a list again. I replaced stream-append with stream-cons.  The error is: 

stream-first: contract violation
  expected: (and/c stream? (not/c stream-empty?))
  given: #<stream>

Comment: Should I pursue some sort of inner recursion, perhaps with letrec, to do this task instead? I'm trying to understand your implementation so I can do it myself, as well.

Comment: Try writing a version that operates on a list instead of a stream. That is, your function should consume a list, and produce a list with spaces collapsed. If you can write that successfully, the stream version is easy to convert to.

Comment: I should've approached this as a list problem initially it seems. Your advice was very helpful - I got it working in a list implementation. I will just use stream->list and work with the data that way. Thanks!